# How do I sort by timestamp in dynamodb query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
 results = table.query(
        IndexName='name-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('name').eq('test')
    )
```

I have the above query, which is working as expected. I would like to sort the results based on date, data was added to dynamoDB. How can I sort these data by date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the date attribute the sort key.

This has less to do with the query and more to do with how you are storing your data. Defining a sort key for your items will let DynamoDB know how you want your data sorted.